# Quesiton about interquartile with continous functions

Tags: probability, statistics

I am having trouble understanding how to find the interquartile range for a function when it is defined piece wise.

For example, I have a density function that is a basic triangle ie $f(x)=\frac{x}{16}$ for $0 \le x \le 4$ and $=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x}{16}$ for $4 \lt x \le 8$.

So to be that would imply that I have a distribution function of $F(x)=\frac{x^2}{32}$ for the first case and $\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{32}$ for the second.

Now I know for the interquartile range I want to find the x_1 such that $F(x_1)=3/4$ and the $x_2$ such that $F(x_2)=1/4$ and my IQR would then be $x_1-x_2$.

But my problem occurs in that the distribution is defined piece wise, so I dont know which case to plug into. Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but the cdf for $4\lt x\le 8$ is $-1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{32}$.

Comment: Thank you but why the minus 1?

Comment: There is a constant of integration. Choose the constant so that the cdf at $x=4$ is $1/2$, or alternately choose the constant so that the cdf at $8$ is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error already before this stage. The CDF is the integral of the entire PDF up until the point you are at now. This can include different "pieces" of the definition of the PDF than the one you are currently looking at. In your case, the CDF in the second region is $-1+x/2-x^2/32$, not $x/2-x^2/32$. This ensures that it is $1/2$, i.e. the area of the first region, when $x=4$. In calculus language, you forgot about $+C$.

As for your actual question, you just have to figure out what the range of each of the pieces is and plug into that one. For example, $F(x)=3/4$ will have to happen in the second piece because the range of the first piece is $[0,1/2]$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense for now about why we need the minus 1 to make it 1/2 of the area. But what if it wasnt so symetric? or it was more then two possibilities?

Comment: @PersonaA It's just that you have to integrate the entire density up to wherever you're at, so you need to add up the total area of any "pieces" that are to the left of where you're at.